# Docker build for Ubuntu 20.04 is failing

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We were using an old ubuntu docker image in past and I am trying to update it to use Ubuntu 20.04. I am getting the following error while building the image:

```
2022-01-07T12:38:09.467-08:00   Step 1/25 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
2022-01-07T12:38:09.467-08:00   20.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
2022-01-07T12:38:09.467-08:00   toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

We did not face this issue earlier when we were building image using older Ubuntu versions.

I am quite new to docker. Following is the starting of my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DOCKER_BUCKET="download.docker.com" \
    DOCKER_VERSION="17.09.0-ce" \
    DOCKER_CHANNEL="stable" \
    DOCKER_SHA256="1323443242" \
    DIND_COMMIT="42432322" \
    DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION="1.21.2" \
    GITVERSION_VERSION="3.6.5" \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
```

Any help on how can I resolve this issue?

PS - we build and then push this image to Amazon ECR.

I solved this issue by changing my docker file to use Ubuntu image from Amazon ECR.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lts/ubuntu:latest
```

Comment: But I haven't tried to build this image for over a month now. Wondering how can I exceed the limit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you cannot build your docker image due to rate limits, if you wait an six hours, you should be able to build again.

So either login to dockerhub and make an account or switch to a vpn to pull.

[https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/02/18/how-to-work-around-dockers-new-download-rate-limit-on-red-hat-openshift#:~:text=The%20company%20now%20has%20a,from%20a%20single%20IP%20address](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/02/18/how-to-work-around-dockers-new-download-rate-limit-on-red-hat-openshift#:%7E:text=The%20company%20now%20has%20a,from%20a%20single%20IP%20address).

Comment: I was on PTO. I am building this today after more than a month.